# Import audio of a video

Tags: import, sound, video

I recorded some videos with my webcam using QuickTime and imported the .mov files as an *ImageList* into MMA using [Import](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/QuickTime.html) which supports QuickTime Version 7 and earlier. **The question is how do I get the audio portion of the .mov file?** When I ask for "Elements" only video elements are returned.

```
Import["Video.mov","Elements"]

{"Animation", "BitDepth", "ColorSpace", "Data", "Duration", 
"FrameCount", "FrameRate", "Frames", "GraphicsList", "ImageList",
"ImageSize", "VideoEncoding"}
```

Comment: When I try to import a .mov file using `Import["temp.mov", "Sound"]`, I get the message: `Import::noelem: The Import element "Sound" is not present when importing as QuickTime.` So maybe translate to some other format like .avi and then import the sound.

Comment: The simplest approach will be to use something external like ffmpeg to extract the audio into a separate file. e.g. `ffmpeg -i sample.mov -vn output.wav`